# Android system file picker dialog controls - how to add a cancel button?

Tags: android, kotlin

Creating an intent with `Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` in Android 10 (API 29) creates a dialog without possibility to close/cancel. Trying to navigate back crashes the app 2 out of 3 times. Same with `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Any ideas how to add cancel buton to the file picker dialog created by an intent?

Comment: Never saw a crash at navigating back. Please post the stack trace of the crash. And post the code that causes the crash.

Answer (score 0):

couldn't find a way to add an explicit cancel button.
but fixed the back button by checking the result code in `onActivityResult`:

```
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        finishActivity(requestCode)
    } else {
        ...
    }
```